# Render a component from array after taking input in react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, material-ui

I'm taking two inputs in Timepicker from Material UI and storing them in an array which I am able to see with console log. I want to generate a table or chip components from that array of objects after it has been stored in the array. But after i click the button noting is rendered. But if i provide the value beforehand it is rendering the chip components. I will provide the source code below, also it seems my array is getting overwritten instead of making new entries every time. Thank you

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Button, Grid, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import Slider from '@material-ui/core/Slider';
import { map } from "jquery";



export default function Test() {


const [slot, SetSlot] = useState("WholeDay")
const [remove, SetRemove] = useState(false)
const [num, SetNum] = useState(1)
const [startsAt, SetStartsAt] = useState("")
const [endsAt, SetEndsAt] = useState("")
// const [mins, SetMins] = useState(60)
const [valued, setValued] = useState(60);

const timeSlots={
    slotList: [
        {id: 1, from: "05:26", to: "04:30", minutes: 60} //This supposed to be empty by default
    ]
}

if (slot === "WholeDay") {
    return <SelectWholeDay />
} else if(slot === "TimeSlot"){
    return <SelectTimeSlot />
}

function handleAddSlots(){
    SetRemove(true)
    timeSlots.slotList.push(
        {id: num, from: startsAt, to: endsAt, minutes: valued}
    )
    SetNum(num + 1)
    console.log(timeSlots)
}

function SelectWholeDay(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Button
                onClick={() => SetSlot("TimeSlot")}
            >Select Time Slot</Button>
        </div>
    )
}

function SelectTimeSlot(){

    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        container: {
            display: 'flex',
            flexWrap: 'wrap',
        },
        textField: {
            marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
            marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
            width: 200,
        },
        }));
        const classes = useStyles();
        function valuetext(value) {
            return `${value}°C`;
        }

        const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
            setValued(newValue);
        };
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Time Slot</h1>
            <form className={classes.container} noValidate>
                <TextField
                    id="time"
                    label="From"
                    type="time"
                    defaultValue="07:30"
                    value={startsAt}
                    onChange={(event) => {SetStartsAt(event.target.value)}}
                    className={classes.textField}
                    InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true,
                    }}
                    inputProps={{
                    step: 300, // 5 min
                    }}
                />
                <TextField
                    id="time"
                    label="To"
                    type="time"
                    defaultValue="07:30"
                    value={endsAt}
                    onChange={(event) => {SetEndsAt(event.target.value)}}
                    className={classes.textField}
                    InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true,
                    }}
                    inputProps={{
                    step: 300, // 5 min
                    }}
                />
                <Slider value={valued} onChange={handleChange} aria-labelledby="continuous-slider" />
            </form>
            <Button
                onClick={() => handleAddSlots()}
            >Add Slot</Button>
            {remove == true ?  <Button
                onClick={() => SetRemove(false)}
            >Remove</Button> : null}
            {/* {payload.map((item) => {
                return(
                    <h1>{item.CampaignOne.ActiveTv}</h1>
                ) 
            })} */}
            {
                timeSlots.slotList.map((item) =>{
                    return(
                        <div>
                            <Chip label={item.from} />
                            <Chip label={item.to} />
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timeSlots` is the same in each render because it's not stored. You may want to consider using useState (like you did with slot and remove)

```js
const [timeSlots, setTimeSlots] = useState({
  slotList: [
      {id: 1, from: "05:26", to: "04:30", minutes: 60} //This supposed to be empty by default
  ]
});

const pushToTimeSlots = (item) => {
  setTimeSlots(timeSlots => timeSlots.push(item));
}

function handleAddSlots(){
  SetRemove(true)
  pushToTimeSlots(
      {id: num, from: startsAt, to: endsAt, minutes: valued}
  )
  SetNum(num + 1)
  console.log(timeSlots)
}
```

Comment: Yes, tried with useState before seeing this, my implementation was also very similar. Thank you